# Is there a good library for dealing with the Modbus protocol in .NET?

Tags: .net, open-source, protocols, plc, modbus

Does anyone know of a good (preferably open source) library for dealing with the Modbus protocol? I have seen a few libraries, but I am looking for some people's personal experiences, not just the top ten Google hits. I figure there has to be at least one other person who deals with PLCs and automation hardware like I do out there.

Open to any other materials that might have been a help to you as well...

Comment: Here you have a complete list of availables libraries http://www.modbus.org/tech.php

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have done a lot of communication with devices for the past few years, since I work for a home automation company, but we don't use Modbus.  We do communication in a standard and open way using Web Services for Devices(WSD) which is also know as [Devices Profile for Web Services(DPWS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devices_Profile_for_Web_Services).

During this time at one point, I did hear of a project called [NModbus](http://code.google.com/p/nmodbus/).  It is an open source library for working with modbus.  I have not used it, but looking at the site and the [changesets](http://code.google.com/p/nmodbus/source/list) on Google Code, it looks pretty active.  You may want to give it a look and even get involved in.  This is the only library that I have heard of that targets .Net.

Comment: Yeah, I saw nmodbus and it looked ok, but last time I tried it it was a bit rough around the edges. I will give it a try. 
Really, I am now interested in reading up on WSD. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Sure thing.  WSD is really the way to go.  Modbus is a very old protocol, I know you may not have a choice, but devices of today are starting to target WSD.

Comment: Thumbs up for NModbus: works really well

Answer (score 6):

AdvancedHMI has a drivers package included that's just great for almost anything comms, though it may be a bit heavy if all you want is Modbus.  AdvancedHMI is also under active development and has a strong user base.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhmi/

NModbus seems to be the most likely to have continued development and there are lots of example projects scattered over the internet.
https://code.google.com/p/nmodbus/

I have liked using this one in the past (Modbus via TCP):
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/16260/Modbus-TCP-class

Modbus to a Siemens Logo PLC is a little different.  I have an example project I could send upon request.

Answer (score 5):

Modbus is a very simple protocol to implement. All information you need can easily be found for free on the Internet.

If you choose to implement it yourself, I will be happy to answer any questions you have along the way.

If you choose to go for a modbus master library I would look for:

- Modbus TCP support.
- Modbus RTU over TCP/UDP and COM-port.
- Configurable byte swapping, word swapping
- Configurable "base" address so you can choose address 1 to actually be address 0 (sounds stupid, but I prefer to always specify addresses the same way they are documented)
- it must support reading several addresses as a block, but it need to be flexible, some modbus slaves will return error if any address in the block is unused/reserved).

Answer (score 1):

FieldTalk Modbus Library - handles all Modbus functions

Comment: Isn't it non-free in terms of pricing, however?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the offering from Colway Solutions http://www.colwaysolutions.com. They have a unique licensing scheme where you pay for each Modbus function code that you desire to use. Its not free but the pricing seems to be low. I also saw a few ports of the library to some popular microcontrollers and RTOS.